# How does Intellisense decide to which project a file belongs to?

Tags: cmake, configuration, project, intellisense, error-checking

I have two CMake projects in Visual Studio 2019 which are completely seperated and have nothing to do with each other.

If i open the first one with the "Open Folder" option and go to my main.c file, the navigation bar (below the file tabs) says "out.elf - Default-Config". I assume this means that Visual Studio has detected that the main.c file belongs to the project with the "Default-Config" configuration.

Now, if I open my second project the same way, the navigation bar says "Miscellaneous Files", so for me it looks like VS has no idea to which project the file belongs (I have only one project open at a time).

The reasons why this bothers me so much is because Intellisense error checking doesn't work, if the project of the file is not detected. In the [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-cpp-intellisense-configuration?view=vs-2019) it says:

> If the Navigation Bar says Miscellaneous Files, then that probably explains why you are not seeing error squiggles under incorrect code, or why a preprocessor macro is not defined.

Unfortunately it doesn't mention how you can avoid or fix that.

So my question is: How does VisualStudio decide to which project a file belongs ? How can I tell VisualStudio that all the files in the folder belong to one project with an already set configuration ? What could be the reasons why it works in one project but not in the other (I know I have not given information about the projects but i just don't know what would be relevant. For me there is no noticeable difference between them.)

I hope the problem is somehow clear (I'm realy struggling to describe it properly). If i have left out some important info just comment and i will add it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So i found the reason why VisualStudio says "Miscellaneous Files" in one project. The project was mixing C and C++ sources, which caused the error checking of Intellisense to break. But i still don't have any idea why Intellisense can't work with .c and .cpp files simultaneously.